# Unexpected exit code for a C program compiled for 32 bit architecture using gcc

Tags: gcc, x86, executable, reverse-engineering

I wrote a simple C program and compiled it for 32 bit architecture.

But when I ran it, I found unexpected results.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(int n) {
    int sum=0;
    int i;
    if (n <= 1 || n >= 0x1000)
        return n;
    for (i=0; i<= n; i++) {
        sum = sum + i;
    }
    return foo(sum);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int n;
    n = foo(200);
    printf("\n\n main about to return %d \n\n", n);
    return n;
}
```

```sh
➜  wbench  gcc -o test.elf test.c -m32 -fno-stack-protector -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -Wall
➜  wbench  ./test.elf 

 main about to return 20100


➜  wbench  echo $?
132
```

I'm expecting `20100` to be the return value, as printed by the main function.

But, I'm getting `132` as the exit code.

I verified using GDB that `20100` is the value in the `eax` register when main is about to return.

```py
➜  wbench  gdb -q test.elf
gdb-peda$ b *main+44
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048492
gdb-peda$ r

 main about to return 20100 

Breakpoint 1, 0x08048492 in main ()

   0x8048489 <main+35>: call   0x80482f0 <printf@plt>
   0x804848e <main+40>: mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4]
   0x8048491 <main+43>: leave  
=> 0x8048492 <main+44>: ret    
   0x8048493:   xchg   ax,ax



gdb-peda$ p/d $eax
$1 = 20100
gdb-peda$ c
[Inferior 1 (process 32172) exited with code 0204]
Warning: not running or target is remote
gdb-peda$ p/d 0204
$2 = 132
```

I even verified that when control is transferred back to `__libc_start_main` and `exit` function is being called, `20100` is being pushed as argument to `exit()`.

```py
gdb-peda$ r
 main returning 20100 
Breakpoint 1, 0x08048492 in main ()

gdb-peda$ finish
=> 0xf7e1ca83 <__libc_start_main+243>:  mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
   0xf7e1ca86 <__libc_start_main+246>:  call   0xf7e361e0 <exit>
   0xf7e1ca8b <__libc_start_main+251>:  xor    ecx,ecx
gdb-peda$ si
=> 0xf7e1ca86 <__libc_start_main+246>:  call   0xf7e361e0 <exit>
   0xf7e1ca8b <__libc_start_main+251>:  xor    ecx,ecx
gdb-peda$ x/wd $esp
0xffffd5c0: 20100
```

What could possibly be the reason for this ?

I don't think the exit code `132` here has got anything to do with `SIGILL` because when I changed the hardcoded argument to `foo()` from `200` to `2` , the exit code changed to `172` where the expected exit code is `26796`.

Comment: Also note that standard C only supports 0 (a synonym for `EXIT_SUCCESS`) and `EXIT_FAILURE` as return values from `main`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like what you're doing is invalid, as you only have 8 bits to return to the OS.

Assuming you're linking against `libc`:

> When a program exits, it can return to the parent process a small amount of information about the cause of termination, using the exit status. This is a value between 0 and 255 that the exiting process passes as an argument to exit.

As indicated in its documentation [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Exit-Status). Also relevant is this line:

> Warning: Don’t try to use the number of errors as the exit status. This is actually not very useful; a parent process would generally not care how many errors occurred. Worse than that, it does not work, because the status value is truncated to eight bits. Thus, if the program tried to report 256 errors, the parent would receive a report of 0 errors—that is, success.

Comment: The reason there's only 8 bits for the exit code is that the other bits in the `status` you get from `waitpid` are used for other info: whether the low 8 bits are a valid exit status, or if something else is going on.  And what signal caused it to exit, and some other flags.

Answer (score 2):

`20100` decimal is `4E84` hex.
`132` decimal is `84` hex.
Your shell is receiving the return value as only 8 bits.

Answer (score 1):

While your program may be returning 20100, the system only fetches the lowest byte, e.g `return % 256`

So `20100 % 256 = 132`